# Inserting into SQL Server CE database file and return inserted id

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Problem is :

My query

```
INSERT INTO TableName(val1,val2)values(1,2);
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

When I run it in run query from server explorer I get the correct result.

But when I use `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteDataTable` I get an error ,... query return null

```
public object ExecuteScalre(string Query, CommandType type) 
{ 
    OpenConnection(); 
    cmd.CommandText = Query; 
    cmd.CommandType = type; 

    object obj = null; 

    try 
    { 
        obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
    } 
    catch 
    { 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        ReleaseResource(); 
    } 

    return obj; 
} 

public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string Query, CommandType type)
{
    OpenConnection();
    cmd.CommandText = Query;
    cmd.CommandType = type;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdaptor = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        dataAdaptor.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseResource();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Notes: it's an `.sdf` file (SQL Server CE), **NOT** `.mdf`, so we can not use stored procedures

Comment: Could you show the code that executes the query?

Comment: public object ExecuteScalre(string Query, CommandType type)
        {
            OpenConnection();
            cmd.CommandText = Query;
            cmd.CommandType = type;
            object obj = null;
            try
            {
                obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                ReleaseResource();
            }
            return obj;

        }


or

Comment: @OsamaElfar Please note that you can edit your question. The code above should be included into the question via editing.

Comment: Remove the try/catch. And check the exception. Creating empty try/catch is an effective way to hide bugs in your code.

Comment: this is the error from tracing :

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 103,Token in error = SELECT ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sql Server Compact Edition** doesn't support multiple statements in one query.
This database (usually) is employeed in a single user scenario, so you could split your command and send two queries to the database, the first inserts the record, the second one returns the @@IDENTITY value.

```
    cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO TableName(val1,val2)values(1,2)", cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: The important part is that the connection should remain open betweeen the two commands

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this is the fact, that you submit two sql commands in one Command-object. The `INSERT` statement did return nothing, thats correct behavior.
Use the *`OUTPUT`*-Clause of TSQL. This will give you values from inserted or deleted rows as a recordset. So you can use *`ExecuteScalar`* to get this value.

Assume you have a table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]  
([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
[Value1] [int] NOT NULL,  
[Value2] [int] NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Using the following SQL gives you the ID of the row inserted as a resultset

> insert Table_1 OUTPUT Inserted.ID values (1,2)

Comment: This would be true if we were talking about Sql Server, (and in that case, also the double statement would work ) but the OP is using Sql Server Compact Edition and there is no OUTPUT available.